# Windows Server 2008 Sleep at night

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server, scheduled-tasks, sleep

I have a Windows Server 2008 home server, that i'm going to sleep during the night. It's BIOS does not support scheduled boot. Can i use some kind of task in the Scheduled Tasks to make it sleep at 10PM and wake it again at 8AM in the morning?

Please help with this problem, I truly appreciate it

Best Regards,
Erik

Comment: You would think that the ServerFault Stack Exchange would be the place to ask questions about servers, but you're probably going to be told to ask this on SuperUser instead because it doesn't fit the community definition of "professional".

Comment: Ok, I'll try to post it there:)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut to `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0` which will put your computer to sleep. Add that to your Task Scheduler to automate your sleep time.

[This tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/) explains how to create a scheduled task to wake from sleep. You'll need to make sure that wake timers are enabled.

I know that these work on desktop, their usefulness on a server is not something I've tested.